# Bootstrap Modal not loading immediately on click button due to jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, cordova, bootstrap-modal, backbone-events, jquery-ajaxq

I am using a bootstrap modal to show the loading message when I am doing an ajax call for validating a URL based on the value returned by statuscode. As soon as user clicks the button a loader message should be displayed and in the behind jQuery ajax call is made.

Bootstrap modal is displayed but with a slight delay instead I want it immediately to show the Bootstrap modal loader message.

Am using Bootstrap, backbone, jQuery. This is basically a Hybrid mobile app developed using web technologies.

Here is what I am doing,

BootStrap Modal code, Basically its hidden (I am opening modal this via javascript)

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog">
    <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg vertical-align-center">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="gifLoad"><img id="loading-image" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /> </div><div id="dataLoad"><p>Please wait..!!!</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button click event is triggered via backbone

```
   openPage: function () {  
        $('.modal').modal('show');         // Opening the bootstrap model on button click    
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
        if (networkState === Connection.NONE) {
            // Check the phone has internet connection or not to proceed further.
            var loaderView = SafetyLoaderView();
            loaderView.render();
            loaderView.appendMessage('Internet Connection seems to be offline');
            loaderView.show();
        }
        else {  
            var textValue = $('#inputValue').val();             // Get the entered value of the input box

            if (textValue === null || textValue === "") {
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
                // If the input box is empty then change the color of the border of thr input box.
                this.$el.find('#inputText').addClass('has-error');
            }
            else {

                var serverUrl = "https://www."+ value1 + value2  + "google.com";              // Forming the URL based on the values entered by the user.
                var status = this.validateURL(serverUrl);           // Calling the validateURL method to validate the URL.

                if (status === 200) {
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                    // If status code is equal to 200 opening the next screen of the application
                    var url = "page2.html";

                    window.location = url;
                }
                else if (status === -1) {
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                    var loaderView = new SafetyLoaderView();         // Handling the status code other than 200,400,404 and 500.
                    loaderView.render();                             // Displaying standard message to the remaining status code.
                    loaderView.appendMessage('The Request could not be completed');
                    loaderView.show();
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Validating URL method which is also a part of a backbone view:

```
validateURL: function (url) {
        var stat = -1;         // Validating the URL. Based on the status code returned, appropriate error message is displayed.
        // New status code can be added to handle the message.

 //------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // ----------- I feel due to ajax call done here its giving me a delay to load modal
        // Instead I want instanly, if I use alert box that is displayed immediately  

//------------------------------------------------------------------


        $.ajax(url, {
            async: false,
            statusCode: {
                200: function (response) {
                    stat = 200;
                },
                400: function (response) {
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');     // Hiding the modal
                    var loaderView = new SafetyLoaderView();
                    loaderView.render();
                    loaderView.appendMessage('The Request could not be understood');
                    loaderView.show();
                    stat = 400;
                },
                404: function (response) {
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');         // Hiding the modal
                    var loaderView = new SafetyLoaderView();
                    loaderView.render();
                    loaderView.appendMessage('Requested URL not found');
                    loaderView.show();
                    stat = 404;
                },
                500: function (response) {
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');        // Hiding the modal
                    var loaderView = new SafetyLoaderView();
                    loaderView.render();
                    loaderView.appendMessage('Internal server error');
                    loaderView.show();
                    stat = 201;
                },
            },
        });
        return stat;
    },
```

If I wont call validateURL method, then the Bootstrap modal loads instantly.

**My question is how to show this loader modal during ajax call.?**

Comment: Your second line of code of the `openPage` handler => `$('.modal').modal('hide'); ` ?? To open the modal you need to use `.modal('show')`

Comment: @Mivaweb : That was by mistake. Its show only in my code.

Comment: Shouldn't Async be set to true on your jQuery AJAX call? That way it runs asynchronously to everything else?

Comment: @CrazyPaste : It cannot be set to true, because the ajax request done wont give me a correct response. That is in my case I would always get "Request could not be completed" error dialog, because it wont wait for 200 status code to return something.